# The `xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/"` is marked red in .form xml by Intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, ui-design

I just create GUI form named TestUI in Intellij. And then TestUI.form and TestUI.java are created by IDE as below.

TestUI.java

```
public class TestUI {
}
```

TestUI.form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="TestUI">
  <grid id="27dc6" row-count="1" column-count="1" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager">
    <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
    <constraints>
      <xy x="20" y="20" width="500" height="400"/>
      <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
    </constraints>
    <properties/>
    <border type="none"/>
    <children/>
  </grid>
</form>
```

The strange thing is that the java file is empty and the form file cannot be opened as graphical interface. What's more the `xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/"` is marked red by IDE. Can you help me ? How can i open form file as graphical interface?
[image]

Comment: Please open Settings | Editor | File Types, find the "GUI Designer Forms" item in the list and make sure that the *.form entry is present in the "Registered Patterns" list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved by [yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) in comment.